# LINQ expression to filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following `LINQ` expression where I am fetching `Courses`, `Students` that belong to that `Course`, then the `School`'s where the `Student`'s goes to. The following LINQ expression works fine.

However, I need to further, filter it where I need to get `Students` with the `City == 'Colarado'`. How can I alter the following LINQ to my use case.

```
     _dbContext.Courses
         .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
         .Include(c => c.Students)
             .ThenInclude(c => c.Schools)
         .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
         .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need all courses and only filter students - since EF Core 5.0 you can use [filtered include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include):

```
 _dbContext.Courses
     .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
     .Include(c => c.Students.Where(s => s.City == "Colarado"))
         .ThenInclude(c => c.Schools)
     .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: OP: Be sure to read the doco on this feature as there are some caveats to watch out for. If your DbContext is tracking any related students for the related course from previous queries, these students can be still returned for a course even if they don't match the filter condition. Ideally DbContext instances using this feature should only execute `AsNoTracking()` queries to avoid this possibility. I'd imagine this feature in EF Core 5 had some debate between potential usefulness vs. breaking the entity's complete/complete-able state. I'm split, this is normally served by projection.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the filter in the `Where` method.

```
_dbContext.Courses
     .Where(c => c.Id == Id && c.Students.All(s => s.City == "Colarado"))
     .Include(c => c.Students)
         .ThenInclude(c => c.Schools)
     .OrderByDescending(c => c.Id)
     .ToListAsync();
```